# Knockout.js syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova and knockout.js to develop my mobile app.

I'm facing a problem that in HTML editor, contents of the "data-bind" attribute don't get highlighted. [like for example in Webforms or MVC editor]

This isn't a real show-stopper for my app, but without highlighted syntax my HTML templates are way harder to read

Probably not important, but I'll mention it - I've added the knockout.js via Bower

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: no, the issue still persists even after updating to latest Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with Tools for Apache Cordova v10